# Autoit - Word -Style Object COM

Tags: com, ms-word, autoit

I'd like to modify the style  of  text in a Word  document.
I did try with the following syntax  ...perhaps do you have an idea
on what has to be changed in my code ...

Thanks for your advices

```
#include <Word.au3>

Func Main()

$utilisateur = @username & @LF
$ordinateur = @ComputerName & @LF
$servicepack = @OSServicePack & @LF
$cpu = @CPUArch & @LF
$ip = @IPAddress1 & @LF
$domaine = @LogonDomain & @LF
$chemin = @HomePath & @LF

Local $word = ObjCreate("Word.Application")
$word.Documents.add
$word.Visible = 1
$word.Selection.TypeText ($utilisateur & $ordinateur & $servicepack & $cpu & $ip & $domaine & $chemin & $word.Selection.wdPropertyAuthor & $word.wdPropertyAppName)
$word.Selection.WholeStory
$word.Selection.style("Titre 1",$word.ActiveDocument.Styles)

With $word.Selection.Font

.Name = "Arial"
.Size = 20
.bold = True
.italic = true
.Alignment = "wdAlignParagraphLeft"
.ColorIndex = 2
EndWith

with $word.Selection.Style

    .Styles("Titre 1")

    EndWith

;~ FOR IN ( pour manipuler des collections et des tableaux)

sleep(5000)
$word.ActiveDocument.saveas("d:\informations_utilisateur.doc")
$word.Quit(0)

EndFunc

Main()
```

Comment: What's the question? What are you trying to do with your code? What is wrong with the code?

Comment: i'd like to change the default style "normal" into another  example " titre1"

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution

```
$word = ObjCreate("Word.Application")
$word.visible=True
$word.Selection.WholeStory
$word.Documents.Add
$word.Selection.TypeText( "november 26 " )
$word.Selection.WholeStory
$word.Selection.Style= "Titre"
```